# Fortran derived type inheritance

Tags: oop, fortran, derived-types

Let's say I have a derived type `bar_a` that is included in derived type `foo_a` as variable `bar`.
Now I want to extend `bar_a` and create a new derived type named `bar_b`. I tried the following:

```
program main
  implicit none

  ! Base types -----------
  
  type :: bar_a
    integer :: a
  end type bar_a
  
  type :: foo_a
    type(bar_a) :: bar
  end type foo_a
  
  ! Extended types -------
  
  type, extends(bar_a) :: bar_b
    integer :: b
  end type bar_b
  
  type, extends(foo_a) :: foo_b
    type(bar_b) :: bar ! <-- Component ‘bar’ at (1) already in the parent type
  end type foo_b
  
  ! ----------------------

  type(foo_b) :: foo

  print *, foo%bar%a
  print *, foo%bar%b

end program main
```

but I get a compiler error: "the component ‘bar’ at (1) already in the parent type".

Is there a way to extend `foo_a` so that it includes the new derived type `bar_b` as I tried, or is there any way to "override" the `bar` variable declaration? I would like to inherit the type bound procedures that would be a part of `foo_a` in `foo_b`.

Answer (score 2):

When I try to compile I get a better message:

```
aa.f90:21:22:

   10 |   type :: foo_a
      |               2
......
   21 |     type(bar_b) :: bar ! <-- Component ‘bar’ already in the parent type
      |                      1
Error: Component ‘bar’ at (1) already in the parent type at (2)
```

and this seems logical you try to extend `foo_a` with an element with the name `bar`, but the type that you extend (from the definition at line 10) already has a variable `bar` at line 11 and you try to add another `bar` at line 21.

Comment: Is there any way to "override" the declaration? In my case I would like to "transfer" the type bound procedures that would be a part of `foo_a` to `foo_b`.

Comment: That is a different question and you should make that clear in your question (edit the current one or ask a new question), my answer was based on what was asked.

Comment: I am sorry. I awkwardly phrased the question. I edited the question to be more clear.